# CoreOS after some reboot can't load etcd unit with user_data config

Tags: reboot, coreos, deis

I'm trying CoreOS(version 410.0.0 stable) that was installed on disk with this [cloud-config](https://gist.github.com/kikicarbonell/f3873c35732247e9bb5c). All work fine at first boot, but after some days and some reboots the problem was presented with etcd.

When I start the machine the output generate message like:

```
Failed to start Load cloud-config from  /var/

<some output lines>

Failed to start Login service
```

Then when I'm try to login valid user, the console output it's:

```
CoreOS(stable)
Failed Units: 1
   user-cloudinit@var-lib-coreos\x2install-user_data.service
devops@deis-server2~$
```

At this point the system it's wake up, but etcd not is registered with **discovery url** present on [cloud-config](https://gist.github.com/kikicarbonell/f3873c35732247e9bb5c).

Anybody have idea about this problem? And because occure after some reboot?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with the help of [@crawford](https://github.com/crawford). That some steps were applied:

1. remove hostname and discovery lines from `/var/lib/coreos-install/user_data`
2. remove directory `/var/lib/etcd`
3. reboot the system

Then, all work fine. Thanks again to [@crawford](https://github.com/crawford)

Comment: It appears I have to do step 2 & 3 every time I reboot the system.  Is yours surviving a reset now?

Comment: @BryanLarsen I'm sorry but your question is not clear, please add more details or tellme if you need talk via irc chat

Comment: I'm just wondering if your servers are rebooting correctly without issue now?   I get the same console output that you listed in your question unless I do an `rm -rf /var/lib/etcd` before every reboot.

Comment: ohh..well [here][https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/146] is the issue to be raised on the subject, it's open yet. Currently I'm not using CoreOS, but I remember just had to delete things when server presented that error and not every time you restarted. I you can contact with pepe for more information or follow the issue referenced.

Comment: remember check your CoreOS version, because I post this question some month ago

Answer (score 0):

Over time, as machines come and go, the discovery URL will eventually contain addresses of peers that are no longer alive. **Each entry in the discovery URL has a TTL of 7 days**

It's also possible that a discovery URL can contain no existing addresses, because **they were all removed after 7 days**. This represents a dead cluster and the discovery URL won't work any more and should be discarded.

For more information : https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/cluster-discovery/#existing-clusters

Comment: What does this mean? It means we cannot restart node after 7 days?

Comment: Yes, sometimes your existing addresses can be all removed after 7 days and you cannot restart the child nodes